# Initializing an array of strings with a value that is not constant

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following scenario:

```
char *value1 = decrypt(somestring);
char *value2 = decrypt(somethingelse);
static char *theValues[2] = {value1, value2};
```

This of course causes an error `initializer is not a constant`.
the function `decrypt()` decrypts a value from the user's config file and returns a `char*`. I then have a for-loop that will check each value of `theValues` and compare it to a list of search strings.

If I remove the initialization and then try to copy `value1` and `value2` to `theValues` it crashes because I haven't allocated memory. I could go and malloc it and then copy the contents of value1, etc into the array, however I don't have 2 values like in the example above, I have 50.

Is there a way to initialize `theValues` without having to malloc each element on the array and manually copy the value after the decryption?

Thanks.

Comment: "If I remove the initialization and then try to copy value1 and value2 to theValues it crashes because I haven't allocated memory." Can you show us how you did this? This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your array

```
  static char *theValues[2];
```

Then it has two null pointers, since it is static; and you can fill it with e.g.

```
  if (!thevalues[0]) 
      thevalues[0] = decrypt(somestring);
  if (!thevalues[1])
      thevalues[1] = decrypt(somethingelse);
```

The tests ensure that (assuming `decrypt` don't return a null pointer) the initialization happens once. When the same containing function is called again, only the tests are re-executed, not the initialization.

Comment: That did it. I was trying to strcpy each one as opposed to copying the points. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
static char *theValues[2];

theValues[1] = decrypt(somestring);
theValues[2] = decrypt(somethingelse);
```